# Node JS check if text have "@" and change this text to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I don't know if this is possible, i'm making api than users send a message from front end page and if this massage have like "hi my name is @name" , i need change this @name to some variable than have his name.

```
const name = "Paul"
const city = "Boston"
const userMessage = "Hi my name is @name from @city" 

/** I need create new variable changing @name and @city to recpective variable */
const newMessage = "Hi my name is Paul from Boston"
```

Comment: This is tricky with variables, consider an object instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do that as following:

**Get @... with match():**

```
var city = userMessage.match("@city")[0];
var name = userMessage.match("@name")[0];
```

**Replace @:**

```
city = city.replace("@","");
name = name.replace("@","");
```

**Creating new message**:

```
var newMessage = "Hi " + name + "from " + city;
```